# Deep and shallow cloning with unique pointers

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

No code to show but a general question

If you have a class that has a unique ptr in it, how is the difference between shallow copy and deep
copy relevant?

Comment: since the copy ctor of `std::unique_ptr<T>` is `delete`d, compiler cannot generate the default copy ctor (which performs shallow copy for raw pointers) for a `class` that contains `std::unique_ptr`. And when implementing copy ctor by hand, deep copy must be used to ensure correctness. The deprecated `std::auto_ptr` is an negative example.

Comment: The big difference is that shallow copy is impossible, deep copy isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Shallow copy will leave you with double-free and dangling pointer errors, generally UB.

You can't have shallow copy with `std::unique_ptr<T>` members since the whole point of `std::unique_ptr<T>` is single ownership. On the other hand a type with members of type`std::shared_ptr<T>` will work as expected, since `shared_ptr` is reference counted.

To expand upon the above difference from another direction, in an attempt to better explain the comment, the unique ownership premise of `unique_ptr` requires both `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr<T>&)` and `unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr<T>&)` be  `= delete;` since either would violate the guarantee. Moreover, you'll need to provide some extension method which allowed cloning the pointed to object. `shared_ptr` conceptually involves incrementing a reference count in either case and there's no cloning required.

You could, in theory, allocate objects from some other reusable pool and provide a custom deleter to your `unique_ptr` which does nothing. But why bother? Simply use `shared_ptr` if you want shared ownership.

Comment: “Shallow copy will leave you with double-free and dangling pointer errors, generally UB.” — No, that isn’t true. *Default* copying does. This isn’t the same thing as shallow copying, however. There are implementations of shallow copying that are neither UB nor leak (notably via `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph But isn't default copying shallow copying? What's the difference?

Comment: No it isn’t. “shallow” just means the opposite of deep copying, i.e. no transitive copy constructor calling on nested objects.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I beg to differ with you on that. We clearly have somewhat different ideas of what either of us considers shallow copying. I will, however, read more on the subject and update this answer in the future if my views change.

Comment: It’s an extremely well established terminology. What’s more, the terminology is mostly used in languages which don’t even have a concept of UB (and place much less emphasis on memory leaks, due to GC).

Comment: `unique_ptr(const T&)` you probably mean `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&)` i.e. the copy constructor

Comment: @JHBonarius Yup, I did. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Shallow copying pointers with default copy constructor will leave you with dangling pointers. (pointer to unallocated/freed memory)

`unique_ptr` is non-copyable. The pointer can be only moved into another `unique_ptr` or made into `shared_ptr`. The whole purpose of `unique_ptr` is to have **one** reference (in this case a pointer) to some block of memory

This means that shallow copy with `unique_ptr` is impossible.